# Please explain why there is an S at the beginning of a filepath?

Tags: c++, .net, winforms, xaml

Why is there an 'S' at the beginning of a filepath in the example on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983623%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)? I know that you can use a '@' but what does the 'S' do?

```
Bitmap(S"D:\\Documents and Settings\\Joe\\Pics\\myPic.bmp");
```

Comment: You're looking at the c++ example. =)

Comment: @J.Steen: Lol. (shakes my head).

Comment: In MSDN sample, this code snipet is for C++ not C#.Please correct your tag.

Answer (score 7):

It's a sample for `C++/CLI`, not `C#`. And `S""` in `C++/CLI` means that this is managed string literal.

Check http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235263.aspx

Comment: Thank you, @Ravadre. I had mistaken this sample for the C# one.

Comment: @Tommy You're welcome. You've scared me a bit with that post, a string literal modifier in C# that I don't know about after few years of coding in it, what is happening? Fortunately, it was just a mistake heh.